# When do galvanized pipes in NYC residential water delivery pipes need to be upgraded?

Tags: plumbing, water, code-compliance, pipe

It was suggested that I ask here.

Some residential properties in New York City still have galvanized pipes for the inlet water line.  Since heavy metals from the galvanization can leach into the water, [this kind of pipe is no longer specified as an allow building materials according to NYC plumbing code.](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dob/downloads/pdf/plumbing_code.pdf)

- § PC 605 *does not* specify an allowance for galvanized parts, in
  piping, fitting or joints.
- $ PC 605.3 has a table that does not specify galvanization as an allowed material.  This is in context to [the containing] Section 6, which regards Water Supply and Distribution.
- § PC 702 *does* allow galvanization in **drainage**.
- All other usages in this doc deal with non-water systems, or non-inflows.

But in the plumbing code I cannot find a clause section for grandfathering existing galvanized piping.

- Does a grandfathing clause exist in a superseding city code or law?
- Where might I find the change in law that first disallowed galvanized pipes in this usage? (Wherein may also have been specified how to handle existing installations)

Comment: It sounds like you have a very specific question in mind that is unstated in your post. In general, old things are always grandfathered in; it's just how building codes work. Even if it's not actually written anywhere, it's how inspectors and code enforcers treat the situation.

Comment: Agreed.  I've reworded the question

Answer (score 3):

Generally, law questions are off-topic, so I'll answer in a way that's broadly applicable. For the most part, building components that are no longer code-compliant are grandfathered in until work needs to be done on them. So if you have a section of galvanized pipe that's rusted or clogged, you'll have to replace that section with copper or something else that's permitted by contemporary code. Whether the inspector will allow you to get away with a spot repair using compliant materials or will consider that the repair means the whole system is no longer compliant and needs to be replaced depends heavily on the personality of the inspector, how well you treat him, and the local construction culture. In other words, the law is not really all that relevant here. Be courteous and maybe put on your politics hat, if necessary.